# Why are StartupWMClass changes not permanent?

Tags: .desktop, gnome-dash

I am working on Ubuntu 18.04 and trying to associate an application with its shortcut, so it does not launch on a new icon. The `.desktop` file is in `.local/share/applications/` and not in `/usr/share/applications`.

When I edit this file and add the `StartupWMClass` attribute it works fine. But the changes do not stick. Every time I open the `.desktop` file the changes are gone and the application launches on a new icon again. How can I make these changes permanent?

Below is the file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Shift
Icon=/home/<username>/.local/share/icons/hicolor/1024x1024/apps/shift.png
Version=3.5.0
GenericName=Shift
X-GNOME-FullName=Shift
Comment=Shift
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/opt/shift/resources/../Shift -mailto %u
StartupWMClass=Shift
Categories=Network;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/mailto;
```

The result of  `xprop WM_CLASS` command is: `WM_CLASS(STRING) = "shift", "Shift"`

Comment: Is `Exec=/opt/shift/resources/../Shift -mailto %u` exactly what you have?

Comment: @DKBose yes. This is exactly as it is in the `.desktop` file.